# How famous/popular was Krishna during his time in other countries?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, yuga, kurukshetra

[Kurukshetra war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra_War) is like a transition from dwapara yuga to kaliyuga.

During the war, were people in other countries aware of the war? Did people in other countries know about Krishna?

If it didn't affect their lives in any way in other countries, then is this yuga transition mainly for Indians?

Comment: Well, considering that the Mahabharata took place 5000 years ago, and we don't have any literature from the Greeks or other countries dating to that time, we wouldn't have any contemporaneous accounts of Krishna and the Mahabharata.  But there are references to Krishna in Ancient Greek works dating to much after the time of Krishna.

Comment: Parasikas(Persians),Yavanas(Greek/western) are mentioned to be participated in the army of kouravas. Perhaps they were part of kamboja/Gandhara armies.Also Bahlika(todays part of northern afghanistan and tajikistan) who is shantanu's brother participated in the war.

Comment: I believe , people on western side of greece were still barbarians at that time, Roman empire came much later stage.So there is only remote possibility that they have sophisticated writing system to record what is happening in the world.

Comment: Vivekananda was asked once in England why no one came from India thousands of years ago to teach Vedanta. He said, 'who would we preach to, there were nothing but savages here then'

Comment: There was an episode of battle between Kalyavan and Lord Krishna in which Lord Krishna ran away from the battlefield in order to get Kalyavan killed from Muchukand. Here Kalayavan was said to be from Greece.

Comment: @hanugm: I have read an article on the after affects of Mahabharata war at http://www.veda.harekrsna.cz/encyclopedia/warhistory.htm.  Hope it may be helpful.

Comment: @Aby Kalayavana was actually half-Greek, half-Indian; he was the son of the Brahmin Gargya and a Greek queen as described in he Vishnu Purana: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp140.htm